# How do you you use Jquery with django

Tags: jquery, django

I am learning django 1.8 with python 2.7.6 using Mysql

i can use css with my html in django

but how do i use jquery with my html

i can't find a good tutorial...

Comment: You don't have to find a tutorial for this. It just like when your creating an ordinary HTML with Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Not that simple but with practise you can build great app with Django and Jquery.
Hope this will help.

```
[jquery app with django][1]
[Django with Ajax(similar approch)][2]
[Why use Ajax with Jquery Tutorial with example in Django][3]
```

Yes, Some of this links follows Ajax in jquery code but believe me It's the best we use in programming.
You should use it too cause there are so many usecase of this codes in real programming.
Tried to help you buddy.

```
[1]: http://jbjose.com/index.php/2013/07/tutorial-using-django-and-jquery/
  [2]: http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/ajax.html
  [3]: http://mitchfournier.com/2011/06/06/getting-started-with-ajax-in-django-a-simple-jquery-%20approach/
```

Comment: One more thing. You should degrade the version of Django 1.8 to 1.6 something. Cause It is under development and not a good practice version of django. Use stable one. Python version is good.